# Hard menu button on Galaxy s4

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Trying to get some items in the action bar as text, but on the Galaxy s4 everything that you put like this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="@string/options"/>
```

shows up from the bottom left hard menu button. in the past I have gotten by this by just putting an image button in the action bar, but this time I want it to just be text, though when i do it like this, it still wont show up in the action bar, but rather down once i click the hard menu button.

any ways to deactivate the hard menu button? or atleast get this to just say options in the action bar?

Answer (score 0):

I work with the S3, I'm not sure about the S4 but if you change showAsAction to ifRoom, it should always display in the actionbar regardless if there is an image or not. If you want it to be persistent you would use `android:showAsAction="always"`.